# Socket.io: Always invalid namespace

Tags: angular, express, socket.io

Whatever namespace I write, there will always be an invalid namespace.
What I'm doing wrong?

#### Thanks for helping

Server:

```
const privateNamespace = socketIO(server, {
    path: '/v1/main'
}).of('/api/private');
        
privateNamespace.use(ProtectSocketRoute)
privateNamespace.on('connection', (socket: IWebSocket) => {
    console.log(socket.decoded);
});
```

Client:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as IO from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MainWebSocketService {
    private socket: any;
    constructor() {
        this.socket = IO('http://localhost:8080/api/private', {
            path: '/v1/main',
            query: { token: localStorage.getItem('access_token') || '' }
        });

        this.socket.on('connect', this.handleConnect);
        this.socket.on('error', this.handleError.bind(this, 'error'));
    }

    private handleConnect(): void {
        console.log(`[${this.constructor.name}] connected`);
    }

    private handleError(event: string, error: string): void {
        console.error(`[${this.constructor.name}] socket error emitted:`, {event, error});
    }
}
```

Expected: Successfully connected to namespace.

Actual: `[MainWebSocketService] socket error emitted: {event: "error", error: "Invalid namespace"}`

Comment: any solutions? thanks

Comment: maybe try to remove slashes at the beginning or end